# Probability, distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I was practicing some probability questions when i became stuck on this one and was curious on how i go about working it out.

A random variable X has distribution function F. Find the distribution function of Y = aX + b, where a and b are real constants, in terms of F.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition :
$$F(x)=P(X \leq x).$$

Then :
$$F_Y(x)=P(aX+b \leq x)=P\left(X \leq \frac {x-b}a\right)=F\left(\frac {x-b}a\right).$$

Comment: The OP did not say F is the CDF, so I am not sure how you can take $F(x) = P(X \le x)$. I realize the convention is to use upper case for CDF and lower case for PMF, but here he says "X has distribution function F". In any case, your answer works even if $F$ is the PMF of course.

Comment: CDF is sometimes contracted as DF.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know that...

Comment: Thanks for the help!! do you know how i would solve this following question that leads on from this one??  Suppose that F and G are distributions functions and 0 ≤ λ ≤ 1. Show that λF + (1−λ)G is a distribution function.

Comment: You may show that the resulting function is increasing, right continuous and with limits $0$ at $-\infty$ and $1$ at $\infty$. If it satisfies all that, then it is a CDF.